# Hiding an empty filter query with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide the filter options that do not have products assigned using jQuery. This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

I want to hide options 4, 5, and 8 Megapixels if they do not have products assigned to them.

[image]

I have tried this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('span.jet-filters-counter > span.value:empty').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jet-checkboxes-list__button">
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__decorator">
        <i class="jet-checkboxes-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__label">4 Megapixels</span>
  <span class="jet-filters-counter">
        <span class="counter-prefix">(</span>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <span class="counter-suffix">)</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with the script you tried and relevant framework files from aa CDN

Comment: Snippet plus code does not do anything because the span is not empty. It has a `0`  in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with each loop on every buttons

```js
$(".jet-checkboxes-list__button").each(function() { 
   var btnVal = $(this).find('.value').text();
   if (btnVal < 1) {
       $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jet-checkboxes-list__button">
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__decorator">
        <i class="jet-checkboxes-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__label">4 Megapixels</span>
  <span class="jet-filters-counter">
        <span class="counter-prefix">(</span>
  <span class="value">0</span>
  <span class="counter-suffix">)</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="jet-checkboxes-list__button">
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__decorator">
        <i class="jet-checkboxes-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
  <span class="jet-checkboxes-list__label">4 Megapixels</span>
  <span class="jet-filters-counter">
        <span class="counter-prefix">(</span>
  <span class="value">1</span>
  <span class="counter-suffix">)</span>
  </span>
</div>
```